# angular inject module into multiple modules

Tags: angularjs

I'm loading a module on my base html page called `userFromServer`. I'd like to inject it into both the main app module and also the mixpanel module. However I'm getting an injection error if I try to inject `userFromServer` into `analytics.mixpanel`([angular mixpanel](https://github.com/kuhnza/angular-mixpanel)). Is this a circular dependency error or am I missing something? should `userFromServer` be available to all modules? How can I inject `userFromServer` into both modules?

```
var app  = angular.module('App', ['userFromServer', 'analytics.mixpanel']) 
// main app with currentUser injectable
var mixp = angular.module('analytics.mixpanel', ['userFromServer'])
mixp.config(['$mixpanelProvider', 'currentUser', function($mixpanelProvider, currentUser) {
 // use currentUser here
}]);
```

userFromServer module

```
<body ng-app="App" ng-cloak>
  <base href="/">

  <div class="container">
    <div ng-view=""></div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('userFromServer', [])
      .service('currentUser', function() {
        <% if logged_in %>
          this.name = '<%= @User.name %>';
          this.first_name = '<%= @User.first_name %>';
          this.id = '<%= @User.id %>';
          this.uuid = '<%= @User.profile.uuid %>';
        <% end %>
      })
  </script>


</body>
```

the stack trace is:

```
Failed to instantiate module App due to:

Failed to instantiate module analytics.mixpanel due to:

Unknown provider: currentUser
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting? also please include the userFromServer modelu definition.

Comment: Please, provide full error message (including call stack) and the code for relevant modules. The listed code doesn't contain anything that could cause an error  (except the fact that there's no userFromServer). Also, you're confusing injection with loading. Modules are being *loaded*, there's no problem with circular dependency. Dependencies are *injected*.

Comment: @estus updated with code and stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `currentUser` service instance is injected into `config` block. Only service providers can be injected here.

Since `currentUser` is a constant object that doesn't depend on other services and it should be available during config phase, it may be `constant` service:

```
angular.module('userFromServer', [])
  .constant('currentUser', {
    <% if logged_in %>
      name: '<%= @User.name %>',
      first_name: '<%= @User.first_name %>',
      id: '<%= @User.id %>',
      uuid: '<%= @User.profile.uuid %>'
    <% end %>
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your parent module  `App` already has `userFromServer` injected in it, you don't need to inject it again in `analytics.mixpanel`.

Comment: Actually, you need to load it for consistency it if both modules depend on this module. This is what modularity is about. Modules can be used or tested apart from each other this way.

Comment: @estus The parent module `App` has already listed both `analytics.mixpanel` and `userFromServer` as it's dependency. So there's no need to inject `userFromServer` as a dependency separately for sub-module `analytics.mixpanel` again. 
I agree that if two completely independent modules have a dependency, they you can inject it separately, but here they are *not* independent, rather 1st module `App` already has 2nd module `analytics.mixpanel` as it's dependency.

Comment: If `App` directly depends on `userFromServer` and `analytics.mixpanel` is removed from the app at some point, the app will stop working. Angular allows modules to be loaded in several places exactly to cover such cases, this is a feature of the framework and there's no need to avoid this.